# About list view in activity - android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am making kind of big application, and it consist mostly of 3 activities and ListView components in them.

> MainActivity -> FirstActivity and back
>
> MainActivity  -> SecondActivty and back

**All three have ListView component inside listing their specific list view items.**

> I have a Singleton class called MyMachine which holds all properties
>   of the machine inside and some of them are calculated when the main
>   activity is created.

**What I want to achieve**  here is list all related properties of the machine in the Main, First and Second activities . Its like categorizing properties of same thing in 3 groups.

**The problem I faced is:**

I want a click event on each ListView item. But the listener gives me integer key of the ListView item, which means every property of the machine need to be mapped with certain integer key. But if what is item 1 for FirstActivity is item 0 for Main activity I get wrong values printed when clicked.

Is there a better way to do this?

Basically, how to map string values and properly show them in dialog window when ListView item is clicked across all activities. I can develop functions for this certain purpose but is there a more simple way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` shows data using `Adapter`( usually one of the implementations like `BaseAdapter`, `SimpleAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` is used).

`Adapter` class holds the references to items to be shown and also has a special method `getItemId(int position)`, which has to return an ID for an item at a position in ListView.

So, lets say we have am Item class:

```
public class Property{
  public final long id;
  public final String name;
  public final long price;

  public Property(long id, String name, long price){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

Mapped to some database record:

```
| _id | name | price |
|-----|------|-------|
|  1  | abcd |  123  |
|  2  | efgh |  456  |
```

Then we can use an `ArrayAdpater` to show a set of `Property` items in a `ListView`:

```
public class PropertyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Property>{

    public PropertyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).id;
    }

}
```

And you can get item's id:

```
  ListView listView = <some list view>;
  PropertyAdapter propertyAdapter = < adapter for list view >;

  listView.setAdapter(propertyAdapter);

  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           int itemId = propertyAdapter.getItemId(i);
           //-- this item Id is same as returned by getItemId(), 
           //-- which is id field of Property class
           //-- which is id column in database
        }
  });
```

Comment: I use SimpleAdapter, but getItemId() returns long, not int. And what to do with itemId next :) Ok I will map them with Long not Integer :)

Comment: @Vlad These classes are designed to work with databases hence id can be long. This is a demonstration that, If you follow this pattern in all 3 Activities list views, the `ItemId` will be same as on database, no matter how items are arranged in list views.

Comment: Not sure how this can help me out. It is the same thing as using third prameter of onItemClick function which gives the index of the clicked list item. The only thing I can think of is Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i); and then parse the item object and search for it in my HashMap <Long, String>. Or I dont understand.

Comment: What if I want to add subtitle to each ListView component. Can I use ArrayAdapter like SimpleAdapter with two fields.

Comment: @Vlad You can override `getView()` of an adapter and return a custom `View` for each item. Hence you can create any kind of layout to present an item, with text, or images etc etc.

Comment: In SimpleAdapter you can pass data object, how can I do that in this PropertyAdapter?

Comment: @Vlad `PropertyAdapter` extends `ArrayAdapter<Property>`. This means it can work with objects of `Property` class. `getItem()`, `add()`, `addAll()`, `remove()` methods will work with objects of `Property` class.